# Single quotes in sql string

Tags: php, mysql, string, mysqli, sql-update

I'm using PHP to update a record in my database.
This string has some single quotes in them. I was wondering how I could update this string in the database using sql update.

PHP code:

```
$content = $_POST['content'];

$query = "UPDATE about SET content = '" . $content . "' WHERE about_id = 1";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

As example the content is:

*Hi, my name is Sam and I'm living in the Netherlands. I'm 24 years old and I work at 'DiscoFever'.*

I can't update my record because of the many single quotes in the text. Any solutions for this problem?

Comment: Stop using the MySQL extension. Start using MySQLi or PDO instead, which allow you to use prepared statements with bind variables, which then escapes quotes for you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First thing, you should stop using `mysql_*` and start using `PDO`, you can find quick guide everywhere on internet.

Then, the solution is pretty simple, just apply `mysql_real_escape_string` on your `$content` var, it will allow you to update your content :) And it will also protect you from `SQL injection`.

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string is not needed if using PDO or MySQLi with prepared statements. 
Using PDO/MySQLi without prepared statements defeats their purpose.

Comment: As the `mysql_` extensions are deprecated thus so too is `mysql_real_escape_string` so relying upon it will cause problems in the future. And as @beerwin says - you don't need it anyway with PDO - simply use prepared statements

Comment: This will fail in PHP version 7

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysql_real_escape_string` :-

```
$content=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['content']);
$query = "UPDATE about SET content = '" . $content . "' WHERE about_id = 1";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `filter function` try this code:

```
$content = $_POST['content'];
$query = "UPDATE about SET content    =
'" . filter_var($content,     FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) . "' WHERE     about_id = 1";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die
(mysql_error())
```